# Trim milliseconds part in Informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-cloud

I have value in datetime format `2021-03-08 00:00:00.0`   How to remove the milliseconds part from it?

Like: `2021-03-08 00:00:00.0` to `2021-03-08 00:00:00`

Answer (score 0):

if your target is a table/file and column is in *datetime* format, pls use this -

```
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(dttm_col,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

if your target is a table/file and column is in *string* format, pls use this -

```
TO_CHAR(dttm_col,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

if your target is a file, its better to use string format. if its a table, you need to handle in database side.